# Major Leak at pressure gauge inside my well house

Tags: plumbing

It was just discovered that my well house has been leaking at the pressure gauge profusely for who knows how long I'm going to guess a minimum of 6 weeks. I cannot locate a main water shut off arm as it shows in other diagrams. I have the power off to the well house. I do realize that the whole well house is going to have to be redone more than likely in all the other issues along with that. Can I replace the pressure gauge myself properly with a new one and re- pressurized the tank itself without causing further damage? Is that all they would need to be done urgently to restore water to my house? Or is there more? I am a single mom and cannot afford a repairman out here but I have to have water. I would be ever so grateful for your advice[image][image][image]

Comment: Nobody can tell you if that's the only problem based on these pictures alone. But assuming you can safely shut down and depressurize the system, replacing the leaky pressure gauge should be straightforward - wrench and some thread sealant tape.

Answer (score 1):

Buy a shoulder nipple and an isolation valve when you pick up a new pressure gauge. This will make future gauge changes easy. If it's an oil filled pressure gauge add a 90 degree street elbow so gauge sits upright. Then cut the vent on top of gauge or it may read wrong.
Whatever type of gauge you buy, shut off the isolation valve and open only when you need to check pressure. The gauge will last much longer when it's not subject to fluctuations in pressure.